# GDI+ crashes when loading PNG from IStream

Tags: c++, crash, gdi+, png, stream

I wrote something to load PNG files from a custom C++ IStream via GDI+. It worked great until I ran it on Vista machines. Crashes every time.

When compiled on VS 2008, I found that inserting code into the `IStream::AddRef` method, such as a `cout`, made the problem go away. When compiling with VS 2010, it still crashes regardless of that.

I stripped the program down to its basics. I copied a FileStream straight from Microsoft's documentation. It can load PNGs when using `Bitmap::FromFile`. It can load JPEGs, GIFs, and BMPs via `FromFile` or `FromStream`.

So in short: on Vista, PNG files loaded via `Bitmap::FromStream` crash.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

class FileStream : public IStream
{
public: 
    FileStream(HANDLE hFile) 
    {
        _refcount = 1;
        _hFile = hFile;
    }

    ~FileStream()
    {
        if (_hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            ::CloseHandle(_hFile);
        }
    }

public:
    HRESULT static OpenFile(LPCWSTR pName, IStream ** ppStream, bool fWrite)
    {
        HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFileW(pName, fWrite ? GENERIC_WRITE : GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
            NULL, fWrite ? CREATE_ALWAYS : OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

        *ppStream = new FileStream(hFile);

        if(*ppStream == NULL)
            CloseHandle(hFile);

        return S_OK;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID iid, void ** ppvObject)
    { 
        if (iid == __uuidof(IUnknown)
            || iid == __uuidof(IStream)
            || iid == __uuidof(ISequentialStream))
        {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IStream*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        } else
            return E_NOINTERFACE; 
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void) 
    { 
        return (ULONG)InterlockedIncrement(&_refcount); 
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void) 
    {
        ULONG res = (ULONG) InterlockedDecrement(&_refcount);
        if (res == 0) 
            delete this;
        return res;
    }

    // ISequentialStream Interface
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Read(void* pv, ULONG cb, ULONG* pcbRead)
    {
  ULONG local_pcbRead;  
        BOOL rc = ReadFile(_hFile, pv, cb, &local_pcbRead, NULL);
  if (pcbRead) *pcbRead = local_pcbRead;
        return (rc) ? S_OK : HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Write(void const* pv, ULONG cb, ULONG* pcbWritten)
    {
        BOOL rc = WriteFile(_hFile, pv, cb, pcbWritten, NULL);
        return rc ? S_OK : HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    // IStream Interface
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetSize(ULARGE_INTEGER)
    { 
        return E_NOTIMPL;   
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CopyTo(IStream*, ULARGE_INTEGER, ULARGE_INTEGER*,
        ULARGE_INTEGER*) 
    { 
        return E_NOTIMPL;   
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Commit(DWORD)                                      
    { 
        return E_NOTIMPL;   
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Revert(void)                                       
    { 
        return E_NOTIMPL;   
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE LockRegion(ULARGE_INTEGER, ULARGE_INTEGER, DWORD)              
    { 
        return E_NOTIMPL;   
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE UnlockRegion(ULARGE_INTEGER, ULARGE_INTEGER, DWORD)            
    { 
        return E_NOTIMPL;   
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Clone(IStream **)                                  
    { 
        return E_NOTIMPL;   
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Seek(LARGE_INTEGER liDistanceToMove, DWORD dwOrigin,
        ULARGE_INTEGER* lpNewFilePointer)
    { 
        DWORD dwMoveMethod;

        switch(dwOrigin)
        {
        case STREAM_SEEK_SET:
            dwMoveMethod = FILE_BEGIN;
            break;
        case STREAM_SEEK_CUR:
            dwMoveMethod = FILE_CURRENT;
            break;
        case STREAM_SEEK_END:
            dwMoveMethod = FILE_END;
            break;
        default:   
            return STG_E_INVALIDFUNCTION;
            break;
        }

        if (SetFilePointerEx(_hFile, liDistanceToMove, (PLARGE_INTEGER) lpNewFilePointer,
                             dwMoveMethod) == 0)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        return S_OK;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Stat(STATSTG* pStatstg, DWORD grfStatFlag) 
    {
        if (GetFileSizeEx(_hFile, (PLARGE_INTEGER) &pStatstg->cbSize) == 0)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        return S_OK;
    }

private:
    volatile HANDLE _hFile;
    volatile LONG _refcount;
};



#define USE_STREAM

int main()
{
 Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
 ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
 Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

 Gdiplus::Bitmap *bmp;


#ifndef USE_STREAM
 bmp = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"test.png", false);
 if (!bmp)
 {
  std::cerr << " Unable to open image file." << std::endl;
  return 1;
 }
#else
 IStream *s;
 if (FileStream::OpenFile(L"test.png", &s, false) != S_OK)
 {
  std::cerr << "Unable to open image file." << std::endl;
  return 1;
 }

 bmp = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(s, false);
#endif

 std::cout << "Image is " << bmp->GetWidth() << " by " << bmp->GetHeight() << std::endl;

 Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);


#ifdef USE_STREAM
 s->Release();
#endif

 return 0;
}
```

Tracing and debugging, shows that it does make some calls to the IStream class. It crashes inside of `lastResult = DllExports::GdipCreateBitmapFromStream(stream, &bitmap);` from `GdiPlusBitmap.h`, which is a static inline wrapper over the flat API.

Other than the reference counting, the only IStream methods it calls is `stat` (for file size), `read`, and `seek`.

Call stack looks like:

- ntdll.dll!_DbgBreakPoint@0()  + 0x1 bytes
- ntdll.dll!_RtlpBreakPointHeap@4()  + 0x28 bytes
- ntdll.dll!_RtlpValidateHeapEntry@12()  + 0x70a3c bytes
- ntdll.dll!_RtlDebugFreeHeap@12()  + 0x9a bytes
- ntdll.dll!@RtlpFreeHeap@16()  + 0x13cdd bytes
- ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12()  + 0x2e49 bytes
- kernel32.dll!_HeapFree@12()  + 0x14 bytes
- ole32.dll!CRetailMalloc_Free()  + 0x1c bytes
- ole32.dll!_CoTaskMemFree@4()  + 0x13 bytes
- GdiPlus.dll!GpPngDecoder::GetImageInfo()  + 0x68 bytes
- GdiPlus.dll!GpDecodedImage::InternalGetImageInfo()  + 0x3c bytes
- GdiPlus.dll!GpDecodedImage::GetImageInfo()  + 0x18 bytes
- GdiPlus.dll!CopyOnWriteBitmap::CopyOnWriteBitmap()  + 0x49 bytes
- GdiPlus.dll!CopyOnWriteBitmap::Create()  + 0x1d bytes
- GdiPlus.dll!GpBitmap::GpBitmap()  + 0x2c bytes

I was unable to find anybody else with the same problem, so I assume there's something wrong with my implementation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No repro with the given code and my own test.png on Win7.  The only thing I see wrong is your Stat() function, it doesn't fully initialize the STATSTG.  It contains garbage on the first call.

The call stack shows heap corruption.  Vista has a new and much improved heap manager that diagnoses heap corruption much sooner than XP.  I can only assume that the corruption happens in code not shown.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Win7 either. It only happens on Vista. The above code is all that is needed to crash. My real project actually does set the `stat` struct. However... I think you are right. The culprit looks like `pwcsName`. In my real project code, I am not setting that field during image loading because Microsoft passes the `STATFLAG_NONAME` field, which means they don't want the name. However, it appears that they still use the name on PNG loading if `pwcsName` is non null. My guess is they have something like `if (s->pwcsName) free(s->pwcsName)`, at least on the Vista GDI library.

Comment: By setting the `pwcsName` pointer to non-debug values, I've come to the conclusion that there is different behavior in Vista and Windows 7 GDI+ library (or something associated). Windows 7 will never free it if it passes `STATFLAG_NONAME`, but Vista always will. Setting it to `NULL` when `STATFLAG_NONAME` is set corrects the problem.